Unlocking a locked liquidity pool?
After launching a failed meme token over week ago I have money locked up in my liquidity pool that is doing nothing. I have no or very few low level holders of the token and the amount locked into the liquidity pool could be used for something else now. Is there a way of unlocking it? I don't remember for how long it is locked for, can I find out somehow?
